# How do I rotate the armature of a single bone using a script?

Tags: python, armature

I don't care what form of measurement is used,
I'd like a one line answer to rotate a single bone for example
(target object)
(target bone), (axis to rotate), (amount to rotate)

### for me;

import bpy, mathutils
Enter Pose Mode

MyRig

### Rot(Bone), X, 100

or something similar, is there anything similar to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Rotate the easy way

## Example: rotate('boneCenter', .2, 1)

`def rotate(name, rad, axis=0):
    bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='POSE')
    bpy.context.object.data.bones[name].select = True
    Vector = (1, 0, 0)
    cAxis = (True, False, False)
    if (axis == 1):
        Vector = (0, 1, 0)
        cAxis = (False, True, False)
    if (axis == 2):
        Vector = (0, 0, 1)
        cAxis = (False, False, True)
    bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=rad, axis=Vector, constraint_axis=cAxis, constraint_orientation='GLOBAL', mirror=False, proportional='DISABLED', proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, release_confirm=True)
    bpy.context.object.data.bones[name].select = False`